# Limit appearing to the right of the limit sign in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Why doesn't the u->infinity appear under the limit when I compile? Instead it is appearing to the right of the limit. How do I correct this?

```
\frac{1}{\lim_{u \rightarrow \infty}}
```

Comment: Questions on making things appear in a certain way in LaTeX belong on Super User.

Comment: @David: display issues for Tex often need programmatic solutions.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `\displaystyle`:

Try this:

```
\[\frac{1}{\displaystyle \lim_{u \rightarrow \infty}}\]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{u \rightarrow \infty}}
```

Comment: @Charles: This do the job for $...$ and for \\[\\], too.